# template not picked up correctly for mailers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, templates

I have two mailer classes defined inside a module as below:

**1. app/mailers/my_mailers/mailer_a.rb**

```
module MyMailers
  class MailerA < BaseMailer
    def main
       mail(:to => 'xyz@abc.com', :subject => 'Mail Subject')
    end
  end
end
```

**2. app/mailers/my_mailers/mailer_b.rb**

```
module MyMailers
  class MailerB < MailerA
    def some_method
    end
  end
end
```

**and Base Class of all mailers: app/mailers/base_mailer.rb**

```
class BaseMailer < ActionMailer::Base
    ...
    ...
end
```

Now template and partials of these mailers are stored in (with some html code):

**mailer_a templates**

`app/views/my_mailers/mailer_a/main.html.erb`
`app/views/my_mailers/mailer_a/_header.html.erb`
`app/views/my_mailers/mailer_a/_body.html.erb`
`app/views/my_mailers/mailer_a/_footer.html.erb`

**mailer_b templates**

`/app/views/my_mailers/mailer_b/some_random_templ.html.erb`

**sample content of `app/views/my_mailers/mailer_a/main.html.erb`**

```
<% render partial: 'header' %>
<% render partial: 'body' %>
<% render partial: 'footer' %>
```

**Problem:**
When I try to invoke main() method of MailerB, it should invoke main() method of MailerA (as there's no main available for MailerB class), that in-turn try to call send mail via mail() method by searching for `main` template in `app/views/my_modules/mailer_b` directory. But `mailer_b` views doesn't have any `main` template, so it should fallback to parent class views that is `mailer_a` views directory and start rendering `main.html.erb`

But in my case, the mail received is always empty as if there was no template found and I think  search for template stopped at `app/views/mailer_b/` directory only and not going further up in mailer inheritance.

I have also tried using :template_path mechanism, but result is still same (empty mail)

Anyone who can suggest some fix/solution for such case ? please let me know if I should be giving more details.

Using Rails Version: 3.2.1x

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

why have you used a module for your mailers.Your code is good and i dont see any reason why your templates are not loading accordingly.**Try removing the module** and just use the class like this:-

```
class MailerA < BaseMailer
  default from: "support@mydomain.com"
  ##if needed
  ##layout 'mailer_a'


  def registration_confirmation(user_email)
     //do your stuff with user_email
     mail(:to => user_email, :subject =>"Good to see you")
    ##in case multiple templates in same folder
    ## mail(:to => user_email, :subject =>"Good to see you", :template_name => "main_2")
  end

end##class ends
```

Comment: `mailer_a` and `mailer_b` templates are categorised as mailers for some specific purpose and hence I clubbed them into `my_mailers` module, any new similar mailer for ex: mailer_c will be part of same module.

Comment: I tried removing modules `my_modules` also as suggested but still rails not picking up appropriate template.